# Is expression $(1/x)/(2/x^2)$ is fraction expression or rational expression?

Tags: polynomials, arithmetic, ratio

A rational expression is nothing more than a fraction in which the numerator and/or the denominator are polynomials.  Here are some examples of rational expressions.

$$\dfrac{6}{x-1}, \dfrac{x^2-1}{x^2+1}, x^2+3x+1.$$
We know that  $\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{3}}{\dfrac{2}{5}}=\dfrac{5}{6}$. So $\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{3}}{\dfrac{2}{5}}$ is rational. Now  Similarly we  have

$$\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{x}}{\dfrac{2}{x^2}}=\dfrac{x^2}{2x}.$$ So do we can say that
$\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{x}}{\dfrac{2}{x^2}}$ is rational expression?

Thank you

Comment: It can be simplified to a rational expression of the form $x^2/2x$. Now, normally I would have the concern that this isn't always doable; for example, $2/(1/x^2)$ can be simplified to $2x^2$ (the latter of which is a rational expression) but loses the important detail that it cannot be evaluated at $x=0$. In this specific case, however, $x^2/2x$ doesn't run into this issue.

Comment: Can someone else answer this.

Comment: I edited my answer, if this is any better.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your definition of a fractional expression from what I've found a fractional expression is the same as a rational expression.

If your saying if the example is just a rational/fractional expression it depends on how far the expression is simplified. If the simplifed result has the variables in the denomonator cancelled out the result can be written as a rational function or a non-rational function.

So let's go back to your example of $\frac{\frac{1}{x}}{\frac{2}{x^2}}$. If you simplify it to $\frac{1}{2}x$ its is not a rational expression but if you choose to write it as $\frac{\frac{1}{2}x}{1}$ then its a rational expression.